# Publisher should wait till broker is available

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have a simple publisher, which sends messages to a queue.

```
<int:channel id="publishChannel"/>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="publishChannel" destination="testQueue" session-transacted="true"/>

@Publisher(channel = "publishChannel")
public String sendMessage (String text) {
    return text;
}
```

If the broker crashes, the publisher throws an MessageHandlingException.

Is it possible to block the publisher, till the broker is available again or to make a periodic retry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [add a retry advice to the outbound adapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain).

```
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="publishChannel" destination="testQueue" session-transacted="true>
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="myRetryAdvice" />
    </request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

You can configure the advice with a backoff policy (e.g. exponential) and to take some action when retries are exhausted (rather than throwing the final exception).